# hard time understanding how the handlekey function work on onKeydown in React

Tags: reactjs, input, onkeydown

I create a simple to do list that have add button and have a function inside `OnKeydown` which allow to add by pressing Enter. But I'm still confused how this function work.

```
const Handlesubmit = (e) =>{
      e.preventDefault()
      setTodo([...todo, {text: input, id: Math.random() * 1000}])
  }

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      Handlesubmit(e)
    }
  } 
 return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} value={input} onChange={Handleinput}/>
      <button onClick={Handlesubmit}>Add</button>
      {todo.map(todos => (
        <div key={todos.id}>
       <p> {todos.text} </p> 
       </div>
       ))
      }
    </div>
  );
```

The part that i don't understand is why we need `Handlesubmit(e)` in the `handleKeyDown`. Why `handlesubmit()` wont' work without `e` which is `event` in the handlkeyDown function?

```
const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
           Handlesubmit(e)
        }
      }
```

if without e like

```
const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          Handlesubmit()
        }
      }
```

it show an error  saying

> e is not defined

in my handlesubmit function.

```
  const Handlesubmit = (e) =>{
      e.preventDefault() <<< e is not defined in here
      setTodo([...todo, {text: input, id: Math.random() * 1000}])
  }
```

can someone explain to me?

Comment: tbh, `e.preventDefault` is not required here at all in HandleSubmit so passing `e` is also not required .... whereas `handleKeyDown` uses it so its required there

Comment: but why handlesubmit(e) required e in the paranthesis on handlekeyDown?

Comment: sry, it's not required that is what I'm trying to explain

Comment: Oh the reason that it need is because of e.preventdefault inside handlesubmit function. I get it. Thanks.